# Create table layout using <div/> with width & height as percentages

Tags: html

How to create table layout in HTML only by using  by passing both width & height parameters as percentages, not pixels so that it works as the same in all the browsers ?Also pls suggest some good material or link where I can find the format for required attributes & their values used to accomplish this task.Early replies are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nalaka526/hUFh4/6/

**CSS**

```
.divTable
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: table;
}

.divTableRow
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                H1
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                H2
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                H3
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                H4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                a
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                b
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                c
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell ">
                d
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how i can Center it in page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Do you just want a fluid `<table>` layout? Below is a very basic example of a fluid layout.  Keep in mind, the table will only be as wide as the container it's in.

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr width="25%" height="100%">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr width="75%" height="100%">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```